# Trying to replicate Bootstrap Carousel example... portion of Carousel is hidden by Navigation bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, carousel

I am trying to replicate the carousel template at `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/`

The issue is the carousel is small in height compared to the example on bootstrap site, and starts underneath the navigation bar. So a portion of the carousel is hidden by navigation bar.

Also one can notice the less margin between different sections of the page i.e. navbar, mycarousel, marketing, featurette divs compared to `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/`

The replication can be accessed at `https://jsfiddle.net/oavm512u/`

Can someone help me to resolve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I missed out the `<link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">` that was in plain sight. That made the difference.

Thank you all.